# I am trying to translate a letter grade into a number grade in Java

Tags: java, types

I am aware of making the private variables a character data type, but I was just curious as to why this technique does not work. I have made the simulator as well which is attached. I also know that I do not need methods to make this, but I am trying to get used to coding with methods.

```
public class LetterGrade {
private String grade;
private double numGrade;
private String sign;

public LetterGrade(String grade)
{
}
public double sign()
{
    if(grade.equals("A"))
        numGrade=4.0;
    else if(grade.equals("B"))
        numGrade=3.0;
    else if(grade.equals("C"))
        numGrade=2.0;
    else if(grade.equals("D"))
        numGrade=1.0;
    else if(grade.equals("F"))
        numGrade=0.0;
    else
        System.out.println("");
    if(grade.substring(0,1).equals("-"))
        numGrade=numGrade-0.3;
    else if(grade.equals("+"))
        numGrade=numGrade+0.3;
    if(grade.equals("A+"))
        System.out.println(4.0);
    if(grade.equals("F+"))
        System.out.println("Not a valid input.");
    if(grade.equals("F-"))
        System.out.println("Not a valid input.");
   return numGrade;
}
```

}

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a letter grade: ");
    String grades=input.next();
    LetterGrade grade=new LetterGrade(grades);
    System.out.print("The numeric value is " );
    System.out.println(grade.sign());
}
```

Comment: Please tell us how your code is misbehaving. What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing and what is it not doing that it should be doing. In general you may wish to try to "flesh-out" your question by adding as much pertinent information about your problem as is needed for us to understand it.

Comment: To start with, you never assign the parameter `grade` to anything, as you code stands right now, it should generate a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the field in your constructor. Something like this

```
public LetterGrade(String grade)
{
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

Also, I think you want `String.startsWith(String)` and `String.endsWith(String)` like

```
public double sign() {
    if (grade.startsWith("A")) {
        numGrade = 4.0;
    } else if (grade.startsWith("B")) {
        numGrade = 3.0;
    } else if (grade.startsWith("C")) {
        numGrade = 2.0;
    } else if (grade.startsWith("D")) {
        numGrade = 1.0;
    } else {
        numGrade = 0.0;
    }
    if (grade.endsWith("-")) {
        numGrade -= 0.3;
    } else if (grade.endsWith("+")) {
        numGrade += 0.3;
    }
    if (grade.equals("F+")) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid input.");
    }
    if (grade.equals("F-")) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid input.");
    }
    return numGrade;
}
```